# Formatting hashtable from a single column of a pscustomobject

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble pulling key values from a hashtable JSON Object

```
$personnelresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get www.url.com -WebSession $currentsession             
               # Create Table Format
$personnelresult = @{expression={$_.id};Label="ID";Width=37},
                   @{expression={$_.name};Label="Name";Width=32},
                   @{expression={$_.Atributes};Label="Attributes";Width=128}
               # Print Results
Write-Host "----------------" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Personnel report" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "----------------" -ForegroundColor Green
$personnelresult.details | 
Format-Table $personnelresult
Write-Host "----------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "Count is limited to 15" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "----------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
               # End Results
```

I am getting this:

```
ID        Name       Atrributes
----      ----       ----------
245       Joe        @{age=23; weight=200; height=73}
423       Brendan    @{age=25; weight=173; height=45}
213       Ashley     @{age=28; weight=350; height=20}
```

What I want is this or something similar

```
ID        Name       Attributes
----      ----       ----------
245       Joe        age=23 weight=200 height=73
423       Brendan    age=25 weight=173 height=45
213       Ashley     age=28 weight=350 height=20
```

What I've tried:
I placed this before my table

```
$personnelresult.details.Attributes = $personnelresult.details.Attributes | 
ForEach-Object {
Foreach($p in psobject.properties)
{
    $p.Name
}
}
```

And, I'll get

```
ID        Name       Atrributes
----      ----       ----------
245       Joe        {System.Int32 age=23, System.Int32 weight=200, System.Int32 height=73}
423       Brendan    {System.Int32 age=25, System.Int32 weight=173, System.Int32 height=45}
213       Ashley     {System.Int32 age=28, System.Int32 weight=350, System.Int32 height=20}
```

If there is a better practice or suggestion on handling this data let me know. Additionally, I am dealing with much longer strings than this in the original script. The idea is to show all this information on a single ID in the console.

Comment: Besides the answer below, you might look into Out-GridView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the idea is to have everything in one ID, you can do this:

```
$personnelresult = @{e={$_.id};l="ID";Width=37},
                   @{e={$_.name};l="Name";Width=32},
                   @{e={$_.Atributes.age};l="Age";Width=32},
                   @{e={$_.Atributes.weight};l="Weight";Width=32},
                   @{e={$_.Atributes.height};l="Height";Width=32}
```

That would still get everything on 1 line and leave you with a better way to manipulate the data later on in the pipeline.